# Is it possible to drag DraggableScrollableSheet programmatically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to know how to drag the DraggableScrollableSheet widget to go up or down programmatically. For example, based on a [timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html) class.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('DraggableScrollableSheet'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue[100],
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 25,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: DraggableWidget->Container->DraggableScrollableSheet?

Comment: @DeanVillamia Object-> DiagnosticableTree-> Widget-> StatefulWidget-> DraggableScrollableSheet